# Move Data on Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g

I am doing migration to move data from Ms SQL Server 2000 to Oracle 11g on HP Server machine. I don't know why it is very slow when I load data from file xxx.dat into table in oracle 11g.

Do anyone help me to solve my problem?

Thank,
Ung Sopolin

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the *NOLOGGING* clause when inserting bulk data from files.

```
ALTER TABLE[SPACE] name NOLOGGING;
```

This would turn off logging of DML and DDL actions on the specified table or tablespace. What this basically means is your inserts won't write to the redo logs, which should speed up the whole process. Don't forget to later turn redo logging back on using

```
ALTER TABLE[SPACE] name LOGGING;
```

Comment: I type the command as you gave me, but moving the record still slow. Could you other solution for me? Thank for advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is slow. You might want to use an [SQL Migration tool](http://www.swissql.com/products/index.html) [one way](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration//workbench/index_sqldev_omwb.html) or [the other](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-oracle.aspx).

Comment: I am suing SQL Developer Tool. When I migrate oracle 11g on window, its speed 1000 records. But when I migrate oracle 11g on linux, its speed only 100 records.

Comment: This wasn't clear in your question. Also you'll have to be specific about what's different in the two machines besides the OS if you want anyone to guess at the 10 fold difference.

Comment: I mean that I do migration on different machine but the speed isn't the same. I don't know why in the linux it is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the two Oracle machines are similar in hardware specification I'd suggest looking at the built in Enterprise Manager website site (DBCONSOLE) that should be part of each 11g instance.

There should be a "Performance" tab that will give you a good idea of what is causing the performance difference between the two databases.